# How to find LCM of this equation?

Tags: least-common-multiple

Can $(x+1)(2x-1)$ be the LCM of this biquadratic equation

$$\frac{5x-1}{x+7}=\frac{3x+1}{x+5}$$

Comment: The function $\text{lcm}$ takes *numbers* as inputs, not equations. Please clarify what you mean using the right terms.

Comment: $\text{lcm}(x+5,x+7)\neq (x+1)(2x-1), \forall x\in\mathbb Z$. This can easily be proved using the fact that $\text{lcm}(a,b)=\frac{ab}{\gcd(a,b)}$.

Answer (score 1):

The **lowest common denominator (LCD)** of rational fractions 
$$\frac{5x-1}{x+7}\quad {\rm and} \quad \frac{3x+1}{x+5}$$
is the **lowest common multiple (LCM)** of denominator polynomials
$$ x+7 \quad {\rm and} \quad x+5, $$
which is 
$$ (x+7)(x+5).$$
So, formally, the original equality of rational fractions can be re-written as:
$$\frac{(5x-1)(x+5)}{(x+7)(x+5)}= \frac{(3x+1)(x+7)}{(x+5)(x+7)}.$$